# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror, importerror, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm currently working on creating a Google Chrome extension in Manifest V3 and am attempting to import Chart.js. I am getting the following error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "@kurkle/color". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

The following are my files:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@700&display=swap">
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h4>GOOGLE CALENDAR</h4>
        <h5>Time Tracker</h5>
        <hr></hr>
        <div style="width: 800px;"><canvas id="chart"></canvas></div>
        <script type="module" src="src/donut_chart.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**donut_chart.js**

```
import Chart from "../Chart.js/node_modules/chart.js/auto/auto.js";

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function()
{
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart").getContext('2d');
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'doughnut',
        data: {
            labels: [ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' ],
                datasets: [{
                backgroundColor: [
                    "#59be5b",
                    "#d56328",
                    "#ff1b2d",
                    "#0078d7"
                ],
                data: [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
            }]
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('test').textContent = 'SUCCEED';
});
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Google Calendar Time Tracker",
    "description": "Base Level Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "index.html",
        "default_icon": "hello_extensions.png"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
        "https://*/*",
        "http://*/*"
    ]
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "type": "module"
}
```

I've looked online for solutions to this, and haven't really found anything much. All the solutions seem to suggest I use an HTML link instead of an import statement, but Manifest V3 doesn't allow for any outside links to be included. Any sort of help would be much appreciated!